# Array seems to stop after 7 items

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this odd behavior from a table I am drawing. When I add more than 7 entries to the DB for the table to draw, it seems like it crashes and doesn't draw anything. 7 or less and it works just fine.

I have no idea why it would be doing this???

```
$strSQL = "
SELECT u.username playername
     , IFNULL(a.avatar,'default.jpg') playeravatar
  FROM add_tournament_repeat_guests p
  JOIN nfojm_users u
     ON p.guestID = u.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN nfojm_comprofiler a
     ON u.id = a.user_id
 WHERE p.parent_id = $tournID
";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {  

    if (!in_array($row["playername"], $playernames)) {
        $i=0;
        $indexes[$row["playername"]] = 0;
        $playernames[] = $row["playername"];     
    } else {    
        $indexes[$row["playername"]]++;   
        $i = $indexes[$row["playername"]];
    }  
    if (!in_array($row["playeravatar"], $playeravatars)) {
        $i=0;
        $indexes[$row["playeravatar"]] = 0;
        $playeravatars[] = $row["playeravatar"];     
    } else {    
        $indexes[$row["playeravatar"]]++;   
        $i = $indexes[$row["playeravatar"]];
    }  


  }
    print('<table class="block" style="border:2px solid #999999; width:175px; background-color: aliceblue; margin-top:-7px"><thead><tr><th style="color:white; background-color:#444444; height:35px;"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> </th></tr></thead><tbody>');

   foreach (array_combine($playeravatars, $playernames) as $playeravatar => $playername) {

   print("<tr><td style='padding-left:8px;' class='block'><h4><img src='http://www.arcadeicons.com/images/comprofiler/" . $playeravatar . "' height='35' width='35' style='border-radius:50%'> " . $playername . "</h4></td></tr>");

 }
```

Comment: Further testing shows it's not the number of items, it's getting more than one NULL result for the avatar image. How can I write that better so that 2 or more NULLS dont break the array??

Comment: Can you print your two array $playeravatars and $playernames before array_combine and add it in your question? Also why two different array and then combining them? You can do it like this $player[$row["playeravatar"]] = $player["playername"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$playeravatars` and `$playernames` have different lengths, that's why `array_combine()` returns `FALSE` instead of combined array as you expect ([php.net/array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine))

2 users with different names and without avatars will generate 2 rows in `$playernames`, but only 1 row in `$playeravatars` -- that is the reason of length mismatching

You may write your code simplier:

```
echo '<table class="block" style="border:2px solid #999999; width:175px; background-color: aliceblue; margin-top:-7px"><thead><tr><th style="color:white; background-color:#444444; height:35px;"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> </th></tr></thead><tbody>');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {  
    echo "<tr><td style='padding-left:8px;' class='block'><h4><img src='http://www.arcadeicons.com/images/comprofiler/" . $row['playeravatar'] . "' height='35' width='35' style='border-radius:50%'> " . $row['playername'] . "</h4></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this,it's working well now. Still learning the basics so making plenty of mistakes.